# Filter a Map by values in Java?

Tags: java, object, filter, hashmap, java-stream

I have a map where the values are `GregorianCalendar`/`String` and the keys are `Reminder`/`Contact`:

```
private final Map<Object, Object> elements = new HashMap<>();
```

Another list:

```
List<Reminder> result = new ArrayList<Reminder>
```

I would like to filter a map and create a list by reminder themes.

```
public class Reminder {
    String name;

    String theme;
    ...
}
```

I made a method like this but it doesn't work. The method `getTheme()` is undefined for the type Object.

```
public List<Reminder> filterReminderByTheme(String theme) {
    result = elements.values()
            .stream()
            .filter(reminder -> theme.equals(reminder.getValue().getTheme()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return result;
}
```

Some idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first make sure the value is a `Reminder` before testing it's theme.
The reference you're using is an `Object` one and you won't be able to use the `Reminder` methods even though the methods are defined within the underlying object.

You first need to cast it. To cast it, you have to make sure first that it is indeed an `instanceof` the target class.

```
public List<Reminder> filterReminderByTheme(String theme) {
    result = elements.values()
            .stream()
            .filter(value -> value instanceof Reminder 
                                   && theme.equals(((Reminder)value).getTheme()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> and the keys are Reminder/Contact:

Java thinks they're only Objects... Same for the values

```
Map<Object, Object> elements
```

I suggest you redefine the map to have the appropriate types and `elements.values()` would be the type on the right side, so if you want those as a value list, it should not be the key

```
Map<String, Reminder> elements
```

With that, the filter would be

```
.filter(reminder -> theme.equals(reminder.getTheme()))
```

Comment: I believe the reason why the OP is using `Map<Object, Object>` is because that values can either be  GregorianCalendar or String and the keys can either be Reminder or Contact according to the description. maybe creating a wrapper class would be better?

Comment: Exactly. I know that using Map<String, Reminder> elements it will work. But i must use that way.